# In Bootstrap, how do I get my text to left align?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like 'Text' to left align with 'Key Text'. Currently it sits to the right:

[image: l]

I thought class `pl-0` would do this, but it's not. How do I get 'Text' to left align with 'Key Text' in the example? I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qv3uj2rp/) and snippet:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="modal-content pl-3 pr-3">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body-scrolled border-primary border-bottom p-0 mt-2">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label id="lblFieldName" class="col-5 mb-0 text-primary font-weight-bold">Key Text</label>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
            <div class="row form-inline col-12 mt-2 mb-2 pt-2 pb-2 m-0">
              <div class="row col-12 pl-0 pr-0 mb-2">
                <label for="duration" class="col-2 pl-0">Text</label>
                <div class="col-10 pl-0 d-inline">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<label for="duration" class="col-2 pl-0" style="justify-content:left;">Text</label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`justify-content-start`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) class too - by see demo below:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="modal-content pl-3 pr-3">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="modal-body-scrolled border-primary border-bottom p-0 mt-2">
      <div class="form-row">
        <label id="lblFieldName" class="col-5 mb-0 text-primary font-weight-bold">Key Text</label>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
            <div class="row form-inline col-12 mt-2 mb-2 pt-2 pb-2 m-0">
              <div class="row col-12 pl-0 pr-0 mb-2">
                <label for="duration" class="col-2 pl-0 justify-content-start">Text</label>
                <!-- ADDED 'justify-content-start' -->
                <div class="col-10 pl-0 d-inline">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```