# In Bootstrap, why doesn't my text top align with the adjacent element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/bunhdsyL/

I'm following the documentation here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/

but my 'Text' label still isn't top aligned with the adjacent `textarea` element:

[image]

How do I top align the text with the `textarea`?

Comment: Interesting. Resizing the result window (making it smaller horizontally) seems to fix the problem.

Comment: following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527424/in-bootstrap-how-do-i-get-my-text-to-left-align) - you can use `align-items-start` class

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `.form-inline` class add some things that get in the way of your css, including setting `display:flex;` and `align-items:center` on label elements when the screen is larger than the small breakpoint setting.

[image]

You can add this css to override that behavior:

```
.form-inline label {
   align-items: start !important;
}
```